# Pointers to items in a vector are unstable.

Tags: c++, class, struct

I'm observing some pretty weird behaviour. Here is minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "sparsepp.h"


enum Version {
    hg19,
    hg38
};


enum Base {
    A,
    T,
    G,
    C
};


typedef struct {
    Base ref;
    float a;
    float c;
    float g;
    float t;
} SNV;



class GenomeMap {

private:
    spp::sparse_hash_map<long, SNV*> * hg19_mapping;
    spp::sparse_hash_map<long, SNV*> * hg38_mapping;
    std::vector<SNV> values;

public:
    GenomeMap() {

        hg19_mapping = new spp::sparse_hash_map<long, SNV*>;
        hg38_mapping = new spp::sparse_hash_map<long, SNV*>;

    }

    void add(long hg19pos, long hg38pos, SNV value) {
        values.push_back(value);
        (*hg19_mapping)[hg19pos] = &(values.back());
        (*hg38_mapping)[hg38pos] = &(values.back());
    }

    float get(Version version, long position, Base ref, Base alt) {
        spp::sparse_hash_map<long, SNV*> * mapping = (version == hg19) ? hg19_mapping : hg38_mapping;
        SNV* value = (*mapping)[position];

        if (!value || ref != value->ref)
            return -1;

        switch (alt) {
            case A:
                return value->a;
            case C:
                return value->c;
            case G:
                return value->g;
            case T:
                return value->t;
        }
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid arguments");
    }

    ~GenomeMap() {
        delete this->hg19_mapping;
        delete this->hg38_mapping;
    }
};


int main(void) {
    SNV value = {A, 0.1, 0.2, -1.0, 0.3};

    GenomeMap mapping;
    mapping.add(1, 2, value);
    mapping.add(2, 3, value);
    std::cout << mapping.get(hg19, 1, A, T) << "\n";
    std::cout << mapping.get(hg19, 1, A, T) << "\n";
    std::cout << mapping.get(hg19, 2, T, G) << "\n";
    std::cout << mapping.get(hg19, 2, A, G) << "\n";
    std::cout << mapping.get(hg38, 1, A, T) << "\n";
    std::cout << mapping.get(hg38, 1, A, T) << "\n";
    std::cout << mapping.get(hg38, 2, T, G) << "\n";
    std::cout << mapping.get(hg38, 2, A, G) << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

The `sparsepp.h` header (taken from [this](https://github.com/greg7mdp/sparsepp) repo) defines the hashmap `sparse_hash_map`. When I run this example instead this output

```
0.3
0.3
-1
-1.1
-1
0.3
-1
-1.1
```

most of the time I get:

```
0.3
0
-1
-1.1
-1
-1
-1
1.4013e-45
```

Once in a while the second line is `0.3` as it should be. I believe, there is something terribly dumb I've missed. I tried replacing `sparse_hash_map` with `std::map` from STL, but nothing changed.

Comment: Why not using a smart pointer (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) as the value?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've been coding in a strictly C-compatible subset of C++ for a long time, so I don't know what is `std::unique_ptr` about. I no longer have this limitation, though.

Comment: Here you go: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory

Comment: Don't store pointers to a vector's elements. They become invalid when the underlying storage is reallocated.

Comment: More a question than a comment, but if there is a vector<SVN> v, doesn't an access like v.back() retrieve a copy of the value? if so, what does &(v.back()) then mean?

Comment: @StephanLechner As far as I know, `vector.back` returns a reference, not a copy.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Err - `std::unique_ptr` would be inappropriate - there are two copies of the pointer!  You *could* use `std::shared_ptr` (rather than storing the value in `values`), but the overhead is going to be substantial SNV is 20 bytes, the shared_data structure probably takes at least another 16 bytes (and perhaps 32), and then the individual `new` overhead is probably at least 16 bytes (again, probably 32).  Given that this looks like genetics, there are probably *lots* of these objects, so that would be expensive.

Comment: @EliKorvigo You could take a look at https://isocpp.org/tour to see how modern C++ looks like. It has evolved a lot from C with classes styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is

```
void add(long hg19pos, long hg38pos, SNV value) {
    values.push_back(value);                 // <<<<======= HERE
    (*hg19_mapping)[hg19pos] = &(values.back());
    (*hg38_mapping)[hg38pos] = &(values.back());
}
```

When you push a new value into `values`, you invalidate all the previously allocated pointers.  Your options are:

- Reserve enough space in `values` before you start adding to ensure you never reallocate the vector.  This is only possible if you know the final size before you start.
- Store *indices* into the vector, rather than pointers.  The index (`values.size()-1`) will be stable.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Storing indices as `insigned long` would even be more memory efficient than storing 64 bit pointers.

Comment: Only if you are on 64-bit windows. On all other platforms (in practice) long and pointer are the same size